# What does "typedef char A[max_size]" means?

Tags: c, typedef

I have this portion of code and I don't understand how the first typedef works and what happen when we use it in the struct.

```
#define MAX_BLOCKEDADDRESS_SIZE 256

typedef char BlockedAddress[MAX_BLOCKEDADDRESS_SIZE];

typedef struct Blocked {
int capacity;
int length;
BlockedAddress *mailAddress;
} Blocked;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlockedAddress` is a user defined type that is a 256 `char` array.

```
#define MAX_BLOCKEDADDRESS_SIZE 256
typedef char BlockedAddress[MAX_BLOCKEDADDRESS_SIZE];
```

`Blocked` is a user defined type, a `struct` containing 2 `int` and one pointer members.

```
typedef struct Blocked {
  int capacity;
  int length;
  BlockedAddress *mailAddress;
} Blocked;
```

The member `mailAddress` is a pointer to `BlockedAddress`.
[mailAddress as pointer to array 256 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*mailAddress%29%5B256%5D%3B)